# Что значит скомилировать PHP с опцией?

Tags: веб-программирование, php.ini, php, сессия, компиляция

В книге Лауры Томсон "Разработка Web приложений на PHP и MySQL" есть предложение:

> Другой метод, который может применяться в РНР, заключается в добавлении иден-
> тификатора сеанса к адресу URL. Можно сделать так, чтобы идентификатор сеанса до-
> бавлялся к URL автоматически — для этого следует скомпилировать РНР с опцией
> --enable-trans-sid.

**Что значит скомпилировать PHP c указанной опцией? Правильно ли я понимаю, что надо задать значение этой опции в файле php.ini и запустить созданную php страницу (эту опцию я в файле php.ini не нашел, искал с помощью поиска Notepad++)?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ответ можно найти тут: [мышкой тырц](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-trans-sid)